# Git : list all commits that are both children of revision A and parents of revision B

Tags: git, git-log

Revision A is some days old, revision B some months old. Yet when using `git log A..B` or `git log A...B`, I get revisions that are some years old. That makes no sense to me. How do I single out the history of commits that are **both** children of A **and** parents of B ?

Comment: It would be `B..A` to get everything which is reachable from `A` (so parents of `A`) but not reachable from `B`. (And `A...B` is symmetrical difference, meaning `A..B` PLUS `B..A`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`--ancestry-path`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ancestry-path) option of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> `--ancestry-path`
> When given a range of commits to display (e.g. `commit1..commit2` or `commit2 ^commit1`), only display commits that exist directly on the ancestry chain between the `commit1` and `commit2`, i.e. commits that are both descendants of `commit1`, and ancestors of `commit2`.

In your case, you would say:

```
git log --ancestry-path A..B
```

To get the commits that are both children of `A` and parents of `B`.